# Detect if PHP generator accepts send()?

Tags: php, reflection, generator

Is it possible to somehow detect if a generator can accept any send() command? That is, if it has any line like this:

```
$gen = yield;
```

Use-case is when generators are used to factor out side-effects (as in redux-saga). If no expression depends on the result of any side-effect, all side-effects can be run concurrently (non-blocking IO).

Did not find any useful info in the reflection API: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectiongenerator.php

**Edit**: In short, it should be possible to distinguish between

```php
function gen1() {
  yield $something;
}
```

and

```php
function gen2() {
  $result = yield $something;  // Accepting send()
}
```

Comment: Well, *any* `yield` instruction makes your functions be a generator function, which makes it return a generator that can receive `Generator::send()` calls. If you're manipulating a `Generator` instance, then it's supposed to come from such a function. Whether said function is using the return value of `yield` (which is whatever is passed as parameter to `send()`) is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: @Jeto Well, in my use-case it's very much relevant, since it decides whether concurrency can be used or not. :)

Comment: I just meant to say that any generator function accepts `send` calls. Which you may test by using [`ReflectionFunctionAbstract::is_generator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.isgenerator.php). I may've misunderstood something though; could you provide two basic examples, where one of which should match, and the other one not?

Comment: @Jeto I added two examples. Maybe I can try with the internals email list and see if they know anything. But, looks like a "no". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, and after a bit of additional digging, I'm fairly confident that what you're asking is impossible:

Let's first try to summarize how generators work:

- When a function contains at least one `yield` expression, it becomes a generator function that returns a `Generator` instance.
- A `yield` expression basically does the following:

  1. first, it updates the current value of the generator with its value (the one right after `yield`, or `null` if there is none),
  2. then, it waits until `Generator::send` is called on the generator (`Generator::next()`, which is called when iterating over a generator, is exactly the same as `Generator::send(null)`),
  3. when it receives a value through `Generator::send`, it makes the `yield` expression evaluate to whatever was passed as its parameter,
  4. only then, the function can resume its execution (possibly until the next `yield` expression).

So whether you're writing:

```php
yield;  // same as `yield null;`
```

or

```php
yield 'some value';
```

or

```php
$result = yield;
```

or

```php
$result = yield 'some value';
```

The end result is the same, the `yield` value simply evaluates to `Generator::send`'s parameter. Whether you're using the result of the expression doesn't change anything as far as the generator is concerned.

In other words, it's basically like trying to know whether the return value of a function call, or a boolean expression, was stored into a variable or immediately discarded.

Comment: Yeah, I'll go with this for now. I can imagine a language extension which checks the expression and if it's rhs, right-hand side, of an assignment. Then this could be signaled in the `send()` function, perhaps. But it's far-fetched. Thanks for your feedback!